# How would I go about using Google's Geocomplete in React Native app?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, geocomplete

I'm building a practice app using `React Native` and I'm curious to know how Google's Geocomplete works.  I have the `TextInput` bar set up already along with everything else.  All I need is for this to work.

How should I start this?  How would I use an API for this?  I've looked around SO but I can't seem to find a concrete answer.

Comment: Just for clarity are you after simple GeoCoding of an address and the resultant map update? Your question doesn't really explain what the output is.

Comment: @G0dsquad For example, if I enter the address of a place, as I'm typing it, I want it to automatically complete it for me.

Comment: Ok, then you have a couple of options. Places API is what you want I think, this is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete). You can make API calls to there using `fetch`. Or, you can use a pre-built module from NPM. `googleplaces` looks like a good start, should work fine with React Native: https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleplaces